# HTML table half column

Tags: html, html-table

I've made a html table and when I finished I noticed I made a mistake by having one row with 5 columns while all the others have 3. Is it possible to fix it by making 2 columns only half a column wide or auto adjust it using only html? I do not want to use colspan because its a pretty large table.

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>something</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>these should be</td>
    <td>as long as the others</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> something </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Do you want the first row to span both columns or the bottom right cell to span two rows? I'm unclear on what you're after.

Comment: i want the second row to be as long as the first one without using colspan on the first one. One column should have half the size from the column in the first row. i hope you get what i mean

Comment: @user3657850 clear explanation might help us understand the problem.

Comment: I don't understand why you won't use `colspan`, it exists for this purpose. Why would the size of the table matter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Nested table

If you absolutely don't want to use `colspan`, you could try nesting a table:

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>something</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
        <table border="1">
             <tr>
                 <td>these should be</td>
                 <td>as long as the others</td>
             </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> something </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: FWIW: I shudder at this answer, but it achieves a similar result without `colspan`.

Comment: Thank you! I didnt thought about this. It's the the best solution since I'm to lazy to add 100 colspans.

Answer (score 2):

Defining **`colspan`** might solve your problem.

- `colspan` must be specified based on the row with largest column.
- It is actually used to extend 2 or more columns as per your wish.
- It also hugely depends on underlying columns.

```html
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">Something</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>these should be<td>
        <td>as long as the others</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">Something</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This must solve your issue.

**EDIT**: Since you need to span it without the use of `colspan`, you can use nested table.

```html
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">Something</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table border="0"> <!-- if you want border set it to 1 -->
                <tr>
                    <td>this should be</td>
                    <td>as long as the others</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">Something</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The above method goes little bit tricky. For this example it is easy to implement using above snippet. But for your exact solution, since you need to use it for rows with 5 columns.

**MERGE 5 columns into 1 and span it to 3 columns:**(as implemented below)

```html
<tr>
    <td colspan="3">
        <table border="0"> <!-- if you want border set it to 1 -->
            <tr>
                <td>col 1</td>
                <td>col 2</td>
                <td>col 3</td>
                <td>col 4</td>
                <td>col 5</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: I dont want to use colspan on 100 other elements just because of this row.

Answer (score 0):

```
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">something</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>these should be</td>
<td>as long as the others</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2"> something </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

please see colspan definition here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/td

Comment: I dont want to use colspan on 100 other elements just because of this row

Comment: but you need to if you use table
Maybe you shouldn't use <table>